# Jquery remove doesn't work on clone

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a set of rows to be removed, but when i used the jquery remove it didn't work.
It didn't remove the clone, but it did remove the original. What I want is when the delete button is clicked, the rows which is the parents-parent to be removed.

HTML

```
<tr class="expnedu-edu-record">
                    <td>
                        <select name="expnedu-record-tingkat" class="expnedu-record-tingkat">
                            <option>SD</option>
                            <option>SMP</option>
                            <option>SMA</option>
                            <option>SMK</option>
                            <option>D3</option>
                            <option>S1</option>
                            <option>S2</option>
                            <option>S3</option>
                            <option>Lainnya</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="expnedu-record-tahun-min" class="expnedu-record-tahun-min">
                            <?php
                            $i = date('Y');
                            for($i;$i>=1900;$i--): ?>
                            <option><?php echo $i; ?></option>
                            <?php endfor; ?>
                        </select> - <select name="expnedu-record-tahun-max" class="expnedu-record-tahun-max">
                            <?php
                            $i = date('Y');
                            for($i;$i>=1900;$i--): ?>
                                <option><?php echo $i; ?></option>
                            <?php endfor; ?>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="expnedu-record-instansi" class="expnedu-record-instansi" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="expnedu-record-nilai" class="expnedu-record-nilai" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="button" value="X" class="expnedu-record-delete"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

Jquery

```
    var edu_record = $('.expnedu-edu-record').clone();
$('#expnedu-add-edu').click(function(){
                var new_record = edu_record.clone(false);
                new_record.appendTo('.edu-edit-table');
            });    
    $('.expnedu-record-delete').on('click',function(){
                    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
                });
```

Please provide solution, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are dealing with dynamic elements, you need to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). The event delegation syntax of [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is

```
$(static-ancestor-element).on(event, dynamic-element-selector, handler)
```

so

```
$('.edu-edit-table').on('click', '.expnedu-record-delete', function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

Also use [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to the ancestor tr element

Comment: Amazing.. I tried event delegation before but it didn't work because i didn't set the dynamic element selector..
It works now. Thank you